# Strange result in operation with float numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, frame

I have a strange result with float operation:

```
float a = myView.frame.size.height / 2.0;
float b = (myFrame.size.height / 2.0);
float c = a-b;
```

in debug mode:
a = 201;
b = 201;
c = -3.05176e-05 ???

Why??

Comment: If you print more decimal places for a and b you should see that they differ at around the fifth decimal digit.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is actually in how you are calculating myView.frame.size.height and myFrame.size.height.

If they were both exactly 402 then c would be zero. Division by 2 is exact for normal float numbers. At least one of them is very slightly different from 402. If you need to find the cause of the difference you need to print more digits to see which is not exactly 402 and look at how that variable was calculated.

However, given use of float, you should generally expect rounding error at around the 7th significant digit, so your other option is to treat differences in values around 200 with absolute magnitude less than about 1e-4 as being zero.